# Android Device File Path

Tags: windows-10, android

How do I specify the file path for a connected android device in a command prompt on a windows 10 operating system?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not at all. It’s impossible.

On Windows, access to [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) devices is only possible using Explorer or other specialized software.

MTP does not provide block access but atomic object access. As such, it is not compatible with common file manipulation methods.

Comment: how do you figure sports fan? I mean if it's impossible then how does the device even show up in the list?

Comment: @Adam by the magic of Explorer being written to support MTP devices. It does not mean that the device has a drive letter, path or any other information that can be passed to applications by which to pull or push files to or from it. Sure someone could write a client which presented a standard filesystem device in the same way that there were, in the past, WebDAV or FTP clients built into explorer, but to my knowledge no one has bothered.

Comment: Yeah I really want to believe in magic too Mr Potter but inductive reasoning wise everything turns out to be easy and boring once I am bothered to figure it out. which may or may not happen I guess that's the magic in the universe right there

Comment: No built-in way, but you can access devices via **PowerShell** code. Here's a few lines that reveal all items under **This PC**: `$shell  = new-object -ComObject shell.application;
$pc     = $shell.namespace(17); $pc.items()`

Comment: wanted to provide more infobut question is already closed!

Comment: Linked "Duplicate" provides no working code.

Comment: @Keith then feel free to post a solution to the linked question.

Comment: Let's see if the OP is paying attention. Don't know if PowerShell script suits his purposes.